# Entity Framework Core 5.0 Reference Navigation RequiredAttribute + Migration not working

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

We've just recently upgraded an ASP.NET Core project to 5.0 with all the Entity Framework (nuget) upgrades available - bringing it all to the latest 5.0 release.

When creating a new migration, it appears a reference navigation property attributed with `[Required]` no longer causes the migration to create the column as `NOT NULL`.

Our code (note the `Template` reference navigation property):

```
/// <summary>
/// A document is a completed template
/// </summary>
public class Document
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CompanyRecId { get; set; }
    public int AgreementRecId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// A HistoryId is common to all documents copied from an original document.
    /// Thus;
    /// - A document is created via a template
    /// - A second document is created by the original document.
    /// - The two documents are linked by the same GroupId.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public Guid HistoryId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Creator { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Template Template { get; set; }
```

*...constructors, methods follow*

When creating a migration (`Add-Migration Update17` for instance), the following (`Up`) code is generated:

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Documents_Templates_TemplateId",
            table: "Documents");

        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
            name: "TemplateId",
            table: "Documents",
            type: "int",
            nullable: true,
            oldClrType: typeof(int),
            oldType: "int");

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Documents_Templates_TemplateId",
            table: "Documents",
            column: "TemplateId",
            principalTable: "Templates",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
    }
```

The `TemplateId` column is being changed from the previous `nullable: false` to `nullable: true` - my question is why?

I have read the breaking changes documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/breaking-changes#required-dependent) and the relationships documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#single-navigation-property) which seems to indicate that the functionality has changed, but looks like not in this specific scenario?
When adding a `TemplateId` property (`int?`) with the `RequiredAttribute` on it - the migration works as expected and nothing changes on the `TemplateId` column.

I seem to be missing something or not understanding the documentation clearly - any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This sounds like a bug, consider posting it to their GitHub issue tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issue, I added a property on the `Template` class -

```
public virtual List<Document> Documents { get; set ; }
```

This seemed to give the EF Tools what it needed to detect the `RequiredAttribute` and correctly build the migration.